# Evaluating a Combinatorial summation

Tags: combinatorics

$$aC_0bC_0 + 2aC_1bC_1 + 3 aC_2bC_2 + 4 aC_3bC_3+\cdots+a\cdot aC_abC_a$$ How to go about evaluating this? I know the basic result

$$aC_0bC_a + aC_1bC_{a-1} +  aC_2bC_{a-2} +  aC_3bC_{a-3}+\cdots+a\cdot aC_abC_0 = (a+b)C_a$$

Comment: I prefer using the notation ${n\choose k}$ for combinations. Try writing ${b\choose k}$ as ${b\choose {b-k}}$. Then you will have $\sum_{k=0}^{a} (k+1) {a\choose k}{b \choose {b-k}}$. This should be familiar to you.

Comment: Yes I got that summation. I couldn't simplify that summation. Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments you already have the form $$\sum_{k=0}^a(k+1)\binom{a}k\binom{b}{b-k}\;.$$ Split it in two to get

$$\sum_{k=0}^a(k+1)\binom{a}k\binom{b}{b-k}=\sum_{k=0}^ak\binom{a}k\binom{b}{b-k}+\sum_{k=0}^a\binom{a}k\binom{b}{b-k}\;,$$

apply the identity

$$k\binom{a}k=a\binom{a-1}{k-1}\;,$$

and apply the Vandermonde identity to each summation.

Comment: Ah! Thank you my friend

Comment: @Sriram: You're welcome; glad to help.